# CONTAINSTABLE search term with apostrophe

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying use [`CONTAINSTABLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx) to search for all people whose name starts with "0'Dwye"

I am using:

```
DECLARE @Contact1Query Nvarchar(300)
set @Contact1Query = '("o''Dwye*")'

SELECT *
FROM CONTAINSTABLE(vwCaseContacts_Search, *, @Contact1Query)
```

But I get no results.  If I use:

```
set @Contact1Query = '("Dwye*")'
```

I get results, if I use:

```
set @Contact1Query = '("o''Dwyer")'
```

I get results, but as soon as I combine apostrophe and * I get no results.

```
set @Contact1Query = '("o''Dwye*")'
```

Comment: is you applied full text search on your table

Comment: I believe so as I get some results if I vary my search term if full text search was not enabled I don't thing I'd ever get results.

Comment: does '("o''Dwye"*)' work?

Comment: nope, returns: Syntax error near '*' in the full-text search condition '("o''Dwye"*)'.

Comment: have you looked at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995220/containstable-wildcard-fails-on-phrase-match